# Ruby and File.read

Tags: ruby, file

I am building a build automation script for my javascripts.
I've never used `File.read` before, but I've decided to give it a try, since it saves a line of code.

So here is my code:

```
require "uglifier"
require "debugger"

@buffer = ""

# read contents of javscripts
%w{crypto/sjcl.js miner.js}.each do |filename|
  debugger
  File.read(filename) do |content|
    @buffer += content
  end
end

# compress javascripts
@buffer = Uglifier.compile(@buffer)

# TODO insert js in html

# build the html file
File.open("../server/index.html", "w") do |file|
  file.write @buffer
end
```

But, it doesn't work. `@buffer` is always empty.

Here is the debugging process:

```
(rdb:1) pp filename
"crypto/sjcl.js"
(rdb:1) l
[4, 13] in build_script.rb
   4  @buffer = ""
   5  
   6  # read contents of javscripts
   7  %w{crypto/sjcl.js miner.js}.each do |filename|
   8    debugger
=> 9    File.read(filename) do |content|
   10      @buffer += content
   11    end
   12  end
   13  
(rdb:1) irb
2.0.0-p0 :001 > File.read(filename){ |c| p c }
 => "...very long javascript file content here..."
```

As you can see, in the `irb`, `File.read` works fine. If I put `debugger` breakpoint within the `File.read` block however, it never breaks into debugger. Which means the block itself is never executed?

Also, I've checked the documentation, and File.read is mentioned nowhere.
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html

Should I just ditch it, or am I doing something wrong?

```
%w{crypto/sjcl.js miner.js}.each do |filename|
  File.open(filename, 'r') do |file|
    @buffer << file.read
  end
end
```

This works just fine. However I'm still curious whats up with `File.read`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.read` doesn't accept a block, it *returns* the contents of the file as a String. You need to do:

```
@buffer += File.read(filename)
```

The reason `debugger` shows the contents is because it prints the return value of the function call.

Now, for some solicited advice, if you don't mind:

1. There's no need of doing `@buffer`, you can simply use `buffer`
2. Instead of `var += "string"`, you can do `var << string`. `+` creates a new String object, while `<<` modifies it in-place, and thus is faster and efficient. You're mutating it anyways by doing `+=`, so `<<` will do the same thing.
3. Instead of `File.open` then `file.write`, you can do `File.write` directly if using Ruby 2.0.

Your final code becomes (untested):

```
require "uglifier"
require "debugger"

buffer = ""

# read contents of javscripts
%w{crypto/sjcl.js miner.js}.each do |filename|
  buffer << File.read(filename)
end

# compress javascripts
buffer = Uglifier.compile(buffer)

# TODO insert js in html

# build the html file
File.write("../server/index.html", buffer)
```

If you'd like to make it more functional, I have more suggestions, please comment if you'd like some. :)

Comment: I like to use class variables for something I use over whole file, just so it stands out and I see where it mutates. Thanks for explaining to me how `File.read` works. I usually use << anyway, just got a bit javascripty with +=. Also, good shortcut on File.write

Comment: @JanNetherdrake you mean _instance variables_ and should probably start thinking of unnecessary ones as a code smell. @Dogbert hinted this could be more functional. Indeed: `File.write('../server/index.html', Uglifier.compile( %w{crypto/sjcl.js miner.js}.map { |fn| File.read(fn) }.join ) )`

Comment: @dbenhur, yup, that's what I was going to suggest! :)

Comment: Yes, instance variables. Its just a little build script for myself, so thats why I didn't refactor it.

Comment: But I do appreciate the tips. Thank you.